# Not able to connect Mysql database to presto - No factory for connector mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, presto

I always get this error when trying to start the Presto server in Intellij.

`2015-06-05T19:30:32.293+0530 ERROR main com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer No factory for connector mysql`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No factory for connector mysql
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnection(ConnectorManager.java:131)
at com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager.loadCatalog(CatalogManager.java:88)
at com.facebook.presto.metadata.CatalogManager.loadCatalogs(CatalogManager.java:70)
at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.run(PrestoServer.java:107)
at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

2015-06-05T19:30:32.294+0530 INFO Thread-88 io.airlift.bootstrap.LifeCycleManager Life cycle stopping...

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I installed mysql using brew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When each Presto server starts, it logs which catalogs were loaded.  My guess, is the file is not in the correct location, or you did not restart your Presto servers.  Note, the file must be on every Presto server.

Answer (score 0):

The 'mysql.properties' file should be present in 
presto-main/etc/catalog folder

Also,
'presto-main/etc/config.properties' should be edited.
'../presto-mysql/pom.xml' need to be appended in plugin.bundles shown below

```
$ cat presto-main/etc/config.properties

# sample nodeId to provide consistency across test runs
node.id=ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff
node.environment=test
http-server.http.port=8080

discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080

exchange.http-client.max-connections=1000
exchange.http-client.max-connections-per-server=1000
exchange.http-client.connect-timeout=1m
exchange.http-client.read-timeout=1m

scheduler.http-client.max-connections=1000
scheduler.http-client.max-connections-per-server=1000
scheduler.http-client.connect-timeout=1m
scheduler.http-client.read-timeout=1m

query.client.timeout=5m
query.max-age=30m

plugin.bundles=\
  ../presto-raptor/pom.xml,\
  ../presto-hive-cdh4/pom.xml,\
  ../presto-example-http/pom.xml,\
  ../presto-kafka/pom.xml,\
  ../presto-tpch/pom.xml,\
  ../presto-mysql/pom.xml

presto.version=testversion
experimental-syntax-enabled=true
distributed-joins-enabled=true
```